# how to call a navigation inside a function which is outside from class in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

```
function logOut(ext_id)
{
  console.log(ext_id);
  navigation.replace('UserScreen');
}
```

I want to call a navigation in this function, but it shows me an error like `"Property 'navigation' doesn't exist"`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the navigation object as an argument to the function `logout` likewise : -

```
//Function
function logOut(navigation, ext_id)
      {
        console.log(ext_id);
        navigation.replace('UserScreen');
      }


//Calling statement from your class component
logOut(navigation, ext_id)
```